# how to use proxy in chrome extension on specific domain and url

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, proxy, extension-methods

How to force browsers to use proxy server for specific domains such as google.com or facebook.com

Use case is if google.com or facebook.com are blocked and I want to force connections to these sites through a proxy connection, while direct access to Internet for everything else.

my code is:

***backgroud.js***

```
function FindProxyForURL(url, host) {

    // use proxy for specific domains
    if (shExpMatch(host, "*.google.com|*.facebook.com"))
        return "PROXY yourproxy:8080";

    // by default use no proxy
    return "DIRECT";
}
```

**menifest.json**

```
{
       "background": {
          "scripts": [ "background.js" ]
       },
      
       
       "description": "This chrome extension use for proxy.",
       
    
     
       "author": "no one",
    
     
       "manifest_version": 2,
       "minimum_chrome_version": "26.0",
       "name": "proxy",
       "permissions": [  "<all_urls>", "webRequest", "webRequestBlocking", "storage", "tabs", "proxy", "cookies", "management", "http://*/*", "https://*/*" ],
       "update_url": "https://clients2.google.com/service/update2/crx",
       "version": "0.10"
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to inject your `FindProxyForURL()` function into PAC config as text, and then pass it through `chrome.proxy.settings.set()`. So in your case `background.js` should be:

```js
function FindProxyForURL(url, host) {
    // use proxy for specific domains
    if (shExpMatch(host, "*google.com|*facebook.com"))
        return "PROXY yourproxy:8080";

    // by default use no proxy
    return "DIRECT";
}

config = {
  mode: "pac_script",
  pacScript: {}
};

config.pacScript.data = FindProxyForURL.toString();

chrome.proxy.settings.set(
  {value: config, scope: "regular"},
  function() {}
);
```